# query for selecting N records

Tags: kdb

I have a table `tab` that has cols `date,sym,value` and is sorted from oldest date to the recent.

I am trying to select the past `N` records for each `sym` and am not sure of the query for this. I know that I can select based on `date` being within a range but I needed it based on `sym` irrespective if `value` appeared on consecutive dates or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this with `fby` and the virtual row number column `i`:

https://code.kx.com/q/ref/fby/

```
q){ select from tab where ({y in x#y}[x];i) fby sym }[-2]

date       sym  time                          src price size
------------------------------------------------------------
2014.04.21 AAPL 2014.04.21D16:29:03.253000000 N   24.98 3561
2014.04.21 AAPL 2014.04.21D16:29:03.558000000 N   24.98 2733
2014.04.21 CSCO 2014.04.21D16:28:56.265000000 O   35.6  8390
2014.04.21 CSCO 2014.04.21D16:29:44.572000000 L   35.61 2286
2014.04.21 DELL 2014.04.21D16:29:35.374000000 L   29.57 1444
2014.04.21 DELL 2014.04.21D16:29:39.979000000 N   29.56 216
2014.04.21 GOOG 2014.04.21D16:29:50.569000000 N   41.87 722
2014.04.21 GOOG 2014.04.21D16:29:58.633000000 O   41.9  437
```

Edit: Faster way would be to use functional exec with the 5th argument n(number of records) for each sym.

```
raze{

    //[table;where;by;cols;rows]
    ?[tab;enlist (in;`sym;enlist x);0b;();y]

}[;-2]'[distinct tab[`sym]]
```

https://code.kx.com/q/basics/funsql/

Answer (score 2):

Matt's suggestions using an `fby` and functional select are best if you want all columns in the table returned. If you only need the `date`, `sym` & `price` columns returned you could use

```
q)ungroup select -2#date,-2#price by sym from trade
sym  date       price
----------------------
APPL 2021.03.13 111.77
APPL 2021.03.13 111.85
CAT  2021.03.13 246
CAT  2021.03.13 246.27
GOOG 2021.03.13 206.24
GOOG 2021.03.13 206.21
NYSE 2021.03.13 60.67
NYSE 2021.03.13 60.97
```

Note that this can become tedious when selecting a large number of columns. In those cases it's better to stick with Matt's suggestions.